# android studio unable to resolve dependency for version 25.4.0 or 26 or 27

Tags: android, android-studio

I use android studio 3 but I can't use the google dependency version 25.4.0 ,26 or 27.

I have to use version 25.3.1

I add `google()` to repositories.
[image]

> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0.
>   Failed to download SHA1 for resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.0/appcompat-v7-27.0.0.pom'.
>   For input string: "

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find root **build.gradle** file and add google maven repo inside all projects tag

```
repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {                                  // <-- Add this
            url 'https://maven.google.com/' 
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
```

It's better to use specific version instead of variable version

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
If you're using Android Studio 3.0 or latter version

```
repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
      google()        //---> Add this
}
```

and inject dependency in this way :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
```

Hope this helps you.